# AWS Lambda with Layers included Requests library

Tags: aws-lambda

I prepared Lambda Layers for using BeautifulSoup library to use in Lambda Functions. It's work perfectly.

But when I do the same things for Requests library I always get the same message: `Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'requests'`

What's the different? There are some limits in Lambda Layers?

P.S. I wouldn't like using `botocore.vendored.request`.

Comment: What's the contents of the layer? What version of python is used in Lambda?

Comment: Just Request library, checked on 2.7, 3.6 and 3.7

Comment: Can you display file tree of the layer? Directory structure matters

Comment: both requests and BeautifulSoup are available on this link as public layers. https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers

Comment: @keithRozario Thanks, the layers from Your repo solved the problem!